Does a WIPO patent supersede a US patent?
If a United States utility patent has expired but a virtually identical World Intellectual Property Organization patent is still in effect, would the WIPO patent prevent any US manufacturers from making and selling products in accordance with specs of the expired US patent for purely domestic use? (given that the US is a member state of WIPO)

It seems the question has changed substantially since it was first asked and answered, so this answers the current question:

If a United States utility patent has expired but a virtually identical World Intellectual Property Organization patent is still in effect, would the WIPO patent prevent any US manufacturers from making and selling products in accordance with specs of the expired US patent for purely domestic use? (given that the US is a member state of WIPO)

The US's membership in WIPO alone imposes no special duties on US persons when it comes to purely domestic activity. Patents are always country-specific and so to determine if there is any actionable infringement with respect to a particular country, we have to look at (1) the status of the patent in that country (which we assume here is valid and enforceable in that country), (2) that country's specific laws, and (3) the conduct of the alleged infringer vis a vis that country.
Starting with (3), if conduct is purely domestic, a party generally can't be held subject to another country's laws. Thankfully there is still something called sovereignty, even in the global economy. What a downstream customer, whom the defendant doesn't control, does with their product outside the US is generally not the defendant's concern. A person has no duty to try to prevent the export of a product just because it might theoretically infringe a foreign patent and it's extremely unlikely a US court would enforce a foreign judgment against a domestic party that didn't direct any conduct to and has no relationship with the country in question.
As for (2), again we must look at the laws of the country in question, but I can speak to US law and the inverse situation - a foreign manufacturer sells something to a foreign exporter who tries to import into the US a good covered by a US patent. Under 35 USC 271(a) and (c), infringement requires a sale or offer of sale within the US, or an import into the US. The foreign manufacturer has done neither here; the only claim under (a) or (c) is against the exporter.
Notably under 35 USC 271(b), otherwise known as "inducement", the territorial distinction is removed. So, this might be an avenue of attack against the manufacturer, but the bar is quite high; the defendant has to have specific intent to commit patent infringement or "willful blindness" to its occurrence. (Global-Tech Appliances, Inc. v. SEB S.A.). The only cases I've seen 271(b) applied are when there's a clear relationship and collusion between the direct and indirect infringer and both are perfectly well aware of what's going on and are intending to profit from it. Often it's a parent-sub or affiliate relationship and/or one or the other is clearly a shell company. It's meant for bad actors; it's not something one steps into unknowingly.
So if US law applied, it's unlikely there'd be a claim against the manufacturer based on the bare facts presented. But again, that's the inverse of the question, so we'd have to look at the subject country's laws on indirect infringement to know if they'd apply.
Hopefully it goes without saying that if you or someone you know is considering doing this, and is aware of a specific foreign patent(s) that might be implicated, absolutely get an opinion of counsel first, because the specific facts - especially the manufacturer's relationship with the exporter and/or with the country in question - could matter greatly.

Excellent answer, thanks.  FWIW, in case you can't see the edit, the first paragraph is intact verbatim, I simply deleted the second one that wasn't answered because it wasn't interpreted in the manner I intended, and made that a separate question.  For some reason ohwilleke has chosen to retain a quote from the deleted section in his answer after I suggested its removal to avoid confusion.

Thank you! Gotcha. I can see the edits but didn't look at the whole history. :)  I assume he just didn't get around to editing it yet, but in any case I wanted to address 271(b) specifically because it's the closest US law to applying to the situation you're describing and there's a good bet other countries have something similar.

I actually made the edit for him because it was N/A and he rolled it back for some reason.  Maybe he felt there was a point to be made, but the quote is now orphaned.  Oh well...


Does a WIPO patent supersede a US patent?

No.
This question is based upon a false premise. The distinction between a WIPO patent and a U.S. patent is a category error. There are WIPO patent applications, but there is no such thing as a WIPO patent. You can only have patents under the laws of a particular country.
WIPO provides a process for making a patent application in many countries at once, but it provides no patent of its own. Each country to which the WIPO patent application is provided ultimately evaluates the patent application on its own, even though it may choose, as a matter of national patent office policy, to defer to some determinations made by another patent office. Legally, each national patent obtained with a WIPO patent application stands on its own in the same way that it would if the inventor had applied for a patent separately in every country to which the application was sent.
The national patent office determinations made in response to a WIPO patent application also don't have to be uniform.
For example, suppose that a patent contains five claims. The U.S. could grant all of them, but France might decide that only three can be granted under its interpretation of French patent law.
The WIPO process is akin, for example, to the way that you can apply to many University of California public colleges on a single application. There, each college's own admissions office decides whether or not to admit the student who applied to be a student there, but considers exactly the same application that the student has also submitted to many other colleges in the same University of California system.

would it be a patent violation if the US manufacturer sold a product
made to the specs to another US company, who then shipped it to a
consumer or company in another member nation [where a patent was in
force] where it was promptly disposed of?

Yes. The U.S. companies would be guilty of conspiring with the company in the WIPO member nation where a patent is in force, to violate the member nation's patent laws under the laws of the nation into which it was imported by the ultimate buyer in the WIPO member nation.
This assumes, of course, that both U.S. companies were aware of the total scheme. If the manufacturing U.S. company in the U.S. where the patent had expired was unaware of its U.S. buyer's intentions, only the U.S. buyer company would be guilty of conspiring to violate the importing nation's patent laws.

The closest thing to an "International Patent" is probably the "European Patent". You have a single application, a single investigation, a single patent grant. You can also centrally challenge patents. You still get one individual patent for each signatory state, but everything else is centralized. As-of 2023, the patent holder can furthermore request a "European Patent with Unitary Effect", which further centralizes some stuff. However, not all members of the EPC also participate in the Unitary Patent.

WIPO does the same thing with trademarks as well.

@MichaelHall It sounds like the answer from George White, who is a patent specialist and not just a generalist like me, addresses your follow up question in the comments to this answer. https://law.stackexchange.com/a/102138/9517

I have trimmed back my original question, and expanded and clarified the unanswered portion in a new question here:  https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/102154/are-the-final-stages-of-a-product-s-lifecycle-protected-by-patent

I also edited your answer to remove the portion that referred to the corresponding section of my question that I deleted.

I see you rolled back my edit, but I'm not sure why. Because you're answering a question that wasn't asked.

Your answer presumes a conspiracy that I understand could be interpreted from the original question, but it was clarified several times in since deleted comments, and clearly explained in the new question that I linked to

You can apply to many University of California campuses on a single application. Each of those campuses has different colleges.

@Acccumulation Yeah, definitely pedantic.

To supplement an existing very good answer - patents give the owner the right to try to stop manufacturing, selling, offering for sale, importing and using the item in the jurisdiction that issued the patent.
A patent in the UK would keep an item legally made in the U.S. from being imported into the UK. A UK patent would keep you from making it the UK even if it only going to be exported to the U.S.

I have trimmed back my original question, and expanded and clarified the unanswered portion in a new question here: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/102154/are-the-final-stages-of-a-product-s-lifecycle-protected-by-patent
